# Declare array in Simulink

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, simulink

I have a function on Simulink that copies one input variable to an output according a number (like a DEMUX, but selectable)

[image: Function used on Simulik]

```
function [device,Var_RX1, Var_RX2, Var_RX3, Var_RX4, Var_RX5, Var_RX6, Var_RX7, Var_RX8, Var_RX9, Var_RX10]  = fcn(device, Var_RX)
Var_RX1 = zeros(50,1,'single');
Var_RX2 = zeros(50,1,'single');
Var_RX3 = zeros(50,1,'single');
Var_RX4 = zeros(50,1,'single');
Var_RX5 = zeros(50,1,'single');
Var_RX6 = zeros(50,1,'single');
Var_RX7 = zeros(50,1,'single');
Var_RX8 = zeros(50,1,'single');
Var_RX9 = zeros(50,1,'single');
Var_RX10 = zeros(50,1,'single');    
    if (device == 1)
        Var_RX1 = Var_RX;
    elseif (device == 2)
        Var_RX2 = Var_RX;
    elseif (device == 3)
        Var_RX3 = Var_RX;
    elseif (device == 4)
        Var_RX4 = Var_RX;
    elseif (device == 5)
        Var_RX5 = Var_RX;
    elseif (device == 6)
        Var_RX6 = Var_RX;
    elseif (device == 7)
        Var_RX7 = Var_RX;
    elseif (device == 8)
        Var_RX8 = Var_RX;
    elseif (device == 9)
        Var_RX9 = Var_RX;
    elseif (device == 10)
        Var_RX10 = Var_RX;
    end
end
```

The problem is that when the function is called I have to declare the variables (`Var_RX`) as zeros, otherwise the following problem occurs:

> Output argument 'Var_RX1' is not assigned on some execution paths.

Is there a way to declare those arrays as outputs of this function, and just start the value in the beginning of the program?

EDIT:
I don't explain why I don't want that the zeros appear. 
The problem is when the function is executed on the second time, the value before stored on any variable before read is replaced by zeros.

Comment: Please don't use code snippets in random languages for MATLAB code. They don't work and just add a lot of visual noise to the question.

Comment: You could just use the [in built `selector` block](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/selector.html) which has pretty much this functionality? I don't understand quite why it's an issue declaring them as zeros otherwise...

Comment: @Wolfie Sorry, I don't explain why I don't want that the zeros appear. 
The problem is when the function is executed on the second time, the value before stored on any variable before read is replaced by zeros.

Comment: Use an `isempty` check before setting zeroes?

Comment: Each of your outputs needs to be given a value at each time step, regardless of the inputs, otherwise you get the error message you mentioned that in some execution paths, some variables are not assigned a value. Setting them all to zero at the beginning of the function is one option, the option would to make sure that for each condition of your `if` loop, all outputs from `Var_RX1` to `Var_RX10` are assigned a value, not just the one you're interested in.

Comment: I feel like you should be using a workflow with [enabled subsystems and merge blocks](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/enabled-subsystems.html), that way you get an output of 0 unless your enabled switch is triggered. You're using Simulink, try to take advantage of the in-built blocks rather than putting logic inside function blocks. Otherwise you might as well use MATLAB scripts. If this turns into a question about restructuring your model, it's going to be too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using simulink-if's blocks, then the value isn't replaced every read/write.

[image: Answare]